# Exclude a folder from nginx try_files

Tags: vue.js, nginx, vue-router

I have two locations being served by nginx. I'd like all the `/api/*` paths to be server by uwsgi, and have all other `/` paths served by index.html. I'm using Vue Router, so I also need this `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;`

Here's my full config which works for /, but does not properly exclude /api

```
server {
    listen       8080;
    location ^~ /api {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass localhost:9000;
    }

    location / {
      root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
      index  index.html index.htm;

      location ~ ^(?!/api).+ { { # this doesn't work. i'm trying to ignore /api/* for the rule below.
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
      }
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```